# Laravel Migration: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: database, laravel, migration, mariadb

I receive the error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table`posys`.`#sql-2b94_d2`(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table`purchase_orders`add constraint`
purchase_orders_status_id_foreign`foreign key (`status_id`) references`statuses`(`id`))`

When running my migration.

Here are my migrations:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateStaffTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('position')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('staff');
    }
}
```

And

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePurchaseOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('purchase_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->float('total_price_ex_vat', 12, 2);
            $table->float('total_price_inc_vat', 12, 2);
            $table->string('deliver_to'); 
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('staff_id'); // Foreign key
            $table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('staff');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('supplier_id'); // Foreign key
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('status_id'); // Foreign key
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('purchase_orders');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the migration code (id data type) for the Status Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid error 150, pick one:

- Rearrange the order of `CREATE TABLEs`
- `DISABLE` FKs, do the creates, enable them.
- Don't `ADD` the FKs until all the `CREATEs` have been done.

Answer (score 0):

Your big int is incompatible with your unsigned big int:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('staff_id'); // on purchase orders
```

vs:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id'); // on staff
```

just use a regular big int for `staff_id`, or make your staff's `id` unsigned as well

Comment: thank you for your answer. I changed the `unsignedBigInteger` to `BigInteger` but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try deleting the new tables from your database, and make sure only the tables that remain are listed in the `migrations` table?

Comment: Did you perform the change of `unsignedBigInteger` to `BigInteger` to all the `unsignedBigInteger`'s  or only to `staff_id`?

Comment: Yeah, I have checked all the migrations and changed all foreign keys to `BigInteger `

Comment: @Rob_Beirmann I also added ->unsigned() to the foreign keys and it works now.

`$table->BigInteger('staff_id')->unsigned(); // Foreign key`